# lightswitch html - total amount not calculating

Tags: javascript, lightswitch-2013

I'm trying to build a simple p.o.s entry in lightswitch html. And my problem is the total amount is not calculating in the correct event. I'm new to all this javascript and lightswitch so please forgive my innocence.

I have inserted a breakpoint in my "updateTotal function" the problem I have clearly is that it calls the updateTotal function once I click the addsales detail(When there is no data yet). What needs to happen is that it should call the updateTotal after I selected a product.
What am I doing wrong?

Below is the code I wrote. Can anybody help me? 
    myapp.AddEditSalesHeader.created = function (screen) {

```
 // Write code here.
    //Set the default values of the following fields.
    screen.SalesHeader.InvoiceNo = "(Auto Invoice #)";
    var vTime = new Date();
    screen.SalesHeader.InvoiceTime = vTime;
    screen.SalesHeader.ModePmt = "CASH";
    screen.SalesHeader.Shipment = "PICK-UP";
    screen.SalesHeader.PerDiscount = 0;
    screen.SalesHeader.TotalDiscount = 0;
    screen.SalesHeader.NetAmount = 0;
    screen.SalesHeader.AmountReturn = 0;
    screen.SalesHeader.CashReceived = 0;
    screen.SalesHeader.ChangeDue = 0;
    screen.findContentItem("InvoiceNo").isReadOnly = true;
    screen.findContentItem("InvoiceDate").isReadOnly = true;
    screen.findContentItem("TotalAmount").isReadOnly = true;
    screen.findContentItem("NetAmount").isReadOnly = true;   
};

myapp.AddEditSalesHeader.PerDiscount_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {

    //Compute TotalAmount & NetAmount when PerDiscount value is entered
    contentItem.dataBind("value",
           function (PerDiscount) {
               var vADisc = contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.TotalAmount * (PerDiscount / 100);
               contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.TotalDiscount = vADisc;
               contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.NetAmount = contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.TotalAmount - vADisc;
           });
};

myapp.AddEditSalesHeader.TotalAmount_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {

    function updateTotal() {
        var InvDetail = contentItem.screen.SalesDetails.data;
        var AmtDetail = 0;

        InvDetail.forEach(function (sales) {
            if (isNaN(sales.Amount)) {
                AmtDetail = 0;
           }
            else {
                //Update the TotalAmount
                AmtDetail = AmtDetail + sales.Amount;
            }
        })
        //Display the TotalAmount
        contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.TotalAmount = AmtDetail;
        contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.NetAmount = contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.TotalAmount
                 - contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.TotalDiscount;

    }
    //Set up a databind on screen.SaleDetails.count
    contentItem.dataBind("screen.SalesDetails.count", function () {
        updateTotal();}

 );
    }

    myapp.AddEditSalesHeader.TotalDiscount_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
        // Write code here.
        //Compute PerDiscount & NetAmount when the TotalDiscount value is entered
        contentItem.dataBind("value",
               function (TotalDiscount) {
                   if (TotalDiscount > 0) {
                       contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.PerDiscount = (TotalDiscount / contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.TotalAmount) * 100;
                       contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.NetAmount = contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.TotalAmount - TotalDiscount;
                   }
                   else {
                       contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.PerDiscount = 0;
                   }
               });
    };

    myapp.AddEditSalesHeader.InvTime_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
        // Write code here.
        this.setInterval(
                 function () {
                     var currentTime = new Date();

                     $(element).text(currentTime.toLocaleTimeString());
                 },
                 1000
                 );
    };


    //function CallGetTotAmt(operation) {
    //    $.ajax({
    //        type: 'post',
    //        data: {},
    //        url: '../Web/GetTotAmount.ashx',
    //        success: operation.code(function AjaxSuccess(AjaxResult) {
    //            operation.complete(AjaxResult);
    //        })
    //    });
    //}


    myapp.AddEditSalesHeader.Details_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
        // Write code here.
        //Hide the save command button
        $("[data-ls-tap='tap:{data.shell.saveCommand.command}']").hide();
        //Hide the discard command button
        $("[data-ls-tap='tap:{data.shell.discardCommand.command}']").hide();
    };

    myapp.AddEditSalesHeader.Cancel_execute = function (screen) {
        // Write code here.    
        msls.showMessageBox("Close transaction? Closing will cause any unsaved changes to be discarded.", {
            title: "System Advisory",
            buttons: msls.MessageBoxButtons.yesNo
        })
            .then(function (result) {
                if (result === msls.MessageBoxResult.yes) {
                    myapp.cancelChanges();
                }
            });
    };


    myapp.AddEditSalesHeader.Save_execute = function (screen) {
        // Write code here.
        //Get the total data in SalesHeader
        myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.SalesHeaders.includeTotalCount().execute().then(function (result) {
            var varInvNo = AutoInvNo(result);
            //Set InvoiceNo before saving
            screen.SalesHeader.InvoiceNo = varInvNo;

            var InvDetail = screen.SalesDetails.data;
            var varStock = 0;
            InvDetail.forEach(function (entity) {
                //Update ProductFile StockOnHand that have products in SalesDetail
                varStock = entity.ProductFile.StockOnHand - entity.Quantity;
                entity.ProductFile.StockOnHand = varStock;
                entity.ProductFile.TranCode = "O";
                entity.InvoiceNo = varInvNo;
            })

            myapp.commitChanges().then(null, function fail(e) {
                msls.showMessageBox(e.message, { title: e.title }).then(function () {
                    screen.SalesHeader.InvoiceNo = "(Auto Invoice #)";
                    throw e;
                });
            });

        });
    };


    //Utility
    function AutoInvNo(InvNo) {
        var InvNumber = 1;
        var Entities = InvNo.results;
        //Count the total data in SalesHeader
        Entities.forEach(function (entity) {
            InvNumber = InvNumber + 1;
        });
        //Return InvNumber value
        return InvNumber;
    };


    myapp.AddEditSalesHeader.Print_execute = function (screen) {
        // Write code here.
        var LoadingDiv = $("<div></div>");
        var Loading = $("<h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Loading Report...</h1>");
        Loading.appendTo(LoadingDiv);
        LoadingDiv.appendTo($(element));
        // Get Report
        var HTMLContent = $("<div></div>").html(
            "<object width='650px' height='650px' data='../Reports/BranchSalesReport.rdlc'/>"
            );
        // Make report appear on top of the Loading message
        HTMLContent.css({
            "margin-top": "-50px"
        });
        HTMLContent.appendTo($(element));

    }
```

Comment: have you checked they typo: whether its screen.SaleDetails.count (commented) or screen.SalesDetails.count" (in the code).

alternatively, what happens if you just used the word "value" instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this will solve you problem: alls I have done is add the time interval to the code at the bottom so it knows to check the total multiple times... the post render function is only called once usually so the function inside wasn't actually being called.

```
function updateTotal() {
        var InvDetail = contentItem.screen.SalesDetails.data;
        var AmtDetail = 0;
        InvDetail.forEach(function (sales) {
            if (isNaN(sales.Amount)) {
                AmtDetail = 0;
            }
            else {
                //Update the TotalAmount
                AmtDetail = AmtDetail + sales.Amount;
            }
        })
        //Display the TotalAmount
        contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.TotalAmount = AmtDetail;
        contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.NetAmount =      contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.TotalAmount
                 - contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.TotalDiscount;
}


this.setInterval(
    function () {
//Set up a databind on screen.SaleDetails.count
contentItem.dataBind("screen.SalesDetails.count", updateTotal);
  },1000);
```

and the below code solves the NaN within the Amt Discount and Net Amount:

```
myapp.AddEditSalesHeader.TotalDiscount_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
// Write code here.
//Compute PerDiscount & NetAmount when the TotalDiscount value is entered
contentItem.dataBind("value",
       function () {
           if (contentItem.value > 0) {
               contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.PerDiscount = (contentItem.value / contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.TotalAmount) * 100;
               contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.NetAmount = contentItem.screen.SalesHeader.TotalAmount - contentItem.value;
           }
           else {
               contentItem.value = 0;
           }
       });
};
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Unfortunately that did not work for me. The code that is problematic for me is myapp.AddEditSalesHeader.TotalAmount_postRender = function (element, contentItem) - the complete code is at the top section of my post.

Comment: so you select a product from a DetailsPicker? or is it an item in a table view? and how are you selecting it? by clicking on it or via a switch?

Comment: It is a tile view of the products. Then binds the data(Cash Price, Unit Cost and Discount) to a popup window that will allow the user to enter a discount per item. Then I select it by tapping the tile of the product then hit the check mark at the top. After that it drops the information to my sales details. Sales details will then be updated but not the total amount. How I wish I could post screenshots.

Comment: upload an image to a google+ or dropbox account and just add the link? that may help... or alternatively if the Project is not connected via SQL Server/MySQL, or has any sensitive data then you could share the project and id be more than happy to take a look

Comment: There's the screenshot pls check and let me know if you need more info.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q2f9sgme95etxsj/IRPPosSystem24May15.rar?dl=0    (Link to the project)

Comment: @ Crezzer7 - omg! your my hero!!!! Thanks much! I was actually playing around with that time interval function but couldnt figure out how exactly to use it! Thanks much! I really appreciate it!